# How to get all users from an authorization server using OIDC in spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I've got a spring-boot app that authenticates with OIDC (oauth2) and I'm trying to get a list of all the users from the authorization server - how should I implement this using spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security OAuth2 doesn't have an API for expressing a user repository. It does have a `UserDetailsService` interface, but you'll note that it only has the `loadUserByUsername` method.

If you are building an OAuth 2 authorization server, you could take a look at Spring Data and Spring MVC to expose a query endpoint (using Spring Security to secure that endpoint).

If you are building an OAuth 2 resource server or client that is talking to a third-party authorization server, you could take a look at [`RestTemplate`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) or [`WebClient`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/) to formulate whatever proprietary query your authorization server wants since like @Ronald said, there is no OAuth 2.0 standard for querying users.

Answer (score 0):

When a user signs in into his identity provider his personal information can be accessed by the claims the identity token contains. Or by approaching the userinfo endpoint.

There is no endpoint which returns all the users from the authorization server according to the OIDC standard.